# Access violatuon at address в Delphi

Tags: mysql, delphi

Cобрал программу с использованием `mysql`. Программа работает нормально, и подключение к базе идёт. Но при запуске этой программы на любом другом компьютере, выскакивает ошибка `Access violation at address 008335F0 in module 'Project1.exe'. Read of address 0000002C`. Методом исключения вычислил что данная ошибка появляется когда идёт подключение к базе `SQLConnection1.Connected:=True;`. Как можно решить эту проблему?

Comment: Клиентская либа подложена? Попробуйте взять с собой склиентскую библиотеку mysql (не помню её название)

Comment: P.S Подключение идёт на внешнюю базу данных.

Comment: @nick_n_a Я думаю что нет, я это не делал. Подскажите, как это сделать?

Comment: Просто скопировать dll.

Comment: @nick_n_a Она лежит в директории с Delphi?

Comment: libmysql.dll  не обязательно.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113158/discussion-between-wyles-and-nick-n-a).

Answer (score 0):

Спустя день поисков. Решение оказалось таким.
Не хватало Двух библиотек `dbxmys.dll` и `libmysql.dll`. Они лежат в директории `Delphi/bin`.
Единственное, что я так и не совсем понял, почему Delphi при сборке программы, не подтягивает пак всех нужных библиотек, для программы?! Как мне искать нужные библиотеки, в случаи ещё одного сбоя?

Comment: потому что компилятор может и не знать, какие библиотеки могут понадобиться Вашему приложению. dll может загружаться по имени, которое приходит к примеру с сети/файла

Comment: @KoVadim Но если я использую компоненты Delphi, тот же dbExpress, как я могу знать, какие конкретно мне понадобятся библиотеки? и где их искать?

Comment: читать документацию и форумы.

Comment: Как на счет использования других компонентов для подключения к БД. (`Zeos`, `MyDAC`...)